# CSS3 - fixed transparent navigation: Is there a way to color an element depending on the actually visible background of the element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors

For some project I want to have a transparent fixed navigation of which the color of its contained elements is depending on the current underlying background color.

That means in the simplest case: Depending on scroll - for each element or text within the navigation - if the current visible background is mostly dark then color it white - else color it black.

There is a library which does exactly what i describe for images - *have a look at the following example*: http://www.kennethcachia.com/background-check/fixed-nav.html

The library is hosted here: https://github.com/kennethcachia/background-check

However it looks like for a navigation which is hovering more than images this is pretty complicated as it is not easy to find the parent element(s) which the navigation element currently hovers.

Is there a way in CSS and/or Javascript/JQuery to color an element depending on its ***actual visible background***?

To illustrate what I mean one more example:

Due to user scroll the menu button currently is on a dark background - so color it white:

[image: fixed menu cover dark]

Due to user scroll the menu button currently is on a white background - so color it golden:

[image: fixed menu cover light]

The following snippet shows what I would like to achieve - if my fixed nav hovers a white element make it black - if it hovers a black element make it white - if it hovers an image make it depending on the image pixels (this is what i could achieve with the library).

```css
body {
  background-color:blue;
}

/* If I am on a white or light background, make my color black */
#menu {
  color:white;
  position:fixed;
}

#first {
  height:100px;
  background-color:black;
}

#bar {
  height:100px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
I AM THE MENU - make me black if I am on a white background or on a light image
</div>

<div id="first"></div>

<div id="second">
  <div id="foo">
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="third">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx2yL.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: If you use [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) you should be able to grab the underlaying element, and with that use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). You might need to set the element above to `pointer-events: none`, or hide it, while getting the color though.

Comment: Additionally, if it holds an image, create a _canvas_ element on the fly, draw the image and then get the color from the _canvas_.

Comment: @LGSon : You mean I could generate a canvas with element size on the elements position and size with the element itself being invisible and calculate the avarage color of this canvas? Would be really nice but how could I achieve this?

Comment: If you show a minimal code snippet reproducing the issue, their might be other solutions.

Comment: Since you can grab the x/y position on mouse click, you can also grab the right x/y value from the canvas

Comment: @LGSon Sure I will make a snippet wait a minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that with script would be quite a performance hog, so I would go with `mix-blend-mode` and then use a fallback for browsers that doesn't support, i.e. set a semi-transparent background.

```css
body {
  background-color:blue;
}

/* If I am on a white or light background, make my color black */
#menu {
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;             /*  added  */
  color:white;
  position:fixed;
}

#first {
  height:100px;
  background-color:black;
}

#bar {
  height:100px;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
I AM THE MENU
</div>

<div id="first"></div>

<div id="second">
  <div id="foo">
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="third">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx2yL.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty nice. Also the browser fallback if it is not fully supported yet is not a problem.

However it would be great if I could a) use the borders of the whole element for the effect (instead of every single pixel) and b) define a certain color depending on the result of the "exclusion".

Any way or is this not possible yet?

Comment: @Blackbam If you check this codepen from CSS Tricks https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/ZYdjmZ you'll can elaborate with the values. If to only use border, create a pseudo element and set the blend more to it, though then will white text be white on white background, unless you mix it with a semi-transparent background. The options is many and only you can pick the right one :) ...and I hope this will help you to do that

Comment: Thanks a lot i will check this ;-)

Comment: @Blackbam You're welcome, and btw, here is the full article at CSS Tricks (it has some more info that might be of value) https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/